# Setting message text appearance in Alert Dialog using XML (Android API Level 23)

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I was trying to set the text size of message in an alert dialog, but was unable to after many attempts.  On the other hand, the title and button text sizes can be controlled by the theme's font size simultaneously (set to 14sp in the example below).

The alert dialog was created using the following XML style description, following the approach described in [this blog](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro):

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>

    <!--This controls size of button & title text-->
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyMsgTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyMsgTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

The theme was invoked at runtime using this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setTitle("Remove contact");
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact ?");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Here is what I got:
[image: Alert dialog screenshot]

Apparently, the message text size is much smaller than 22sp.  I could, however, adjust the font size during runtime:

```
dialog.show();

TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if(tv != null)
    tv.setTextSize(22.0f);
```

**Update**
It turns out that if I import *android.app.AlertDialog*, the message size can be adjusted using this method.  However, if I import *android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog*, it can't be adjusted using this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

appcompat-v7 `AlertDialog` message `TextView` has hardcoded style `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` instead of `?android:textAppearanceMedium`. You cannot change its text appearance by overriding the theme attribute.

However you can customize the layout used by appcompat-v7 `AlertDialog`.

#### res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog.Custom</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog.Custom" parent="AlertDialog.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/alert_dialog_custom</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    ...
</style>
```

#### res/layout/alert_dialog_custom.xml

Make a copy of `abc_alert_dialog_material.xml` (find via double-shift in Android Studio), find a `TextView` with `@android:id/message` and alter it as you please.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!  I am just curious how I could find the layout file for appcompat-v7 AlertDialog?  I searched the entire AndroidSDK directory with keyword alert_dialog but could only find alert_dialog_holo.xml, which appears to be the layout for android.app.AlertDialog

Comment: Go to `sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\24.1.1`, open `appcompat-v7-24.1.1.aar` in something that can read ZIP files (e.g. 7-Zip or WinRAR), in the archive go to `res\layout` and get what you need.

Comment: Wonderful!  I would never be able to find this without your help.

Answer (score 10):

You can override `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` style in your styles, something like that:

```
 <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
    </style>
```

and this style will be used instead appcompat style

Comment: Be careful, **it will change this style globally in your app**. Normally it has `android:textColor=?android:textColorPrimary` so it shows correctly in both dark and light themes. If you hardcode the color #000000 here your app will look broken if you use dark themes (black text on dark background). **Prefer a more precisely targeted approach.** If you need to change text appearance in a dialog layout, modify that dialog layout.